# ListView Inside a Grid inside a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, scroll

I have a `ListView` inside a Grid which in turn is inside an "overall `ScrollViewer`".
Users should be able to scroll across the entire page horizontally and then scroll vertically down several child list like elements.  While I am able to scroll horizontally, placing the outer `ScrollViewer` around the page content breaks my `ListViews`

Here is a cut down version of my XAML setup:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Uid="Title" Text="Title"/>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" ZoomMode="Disabled"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                  HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="380" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--My List-->
            <ListView x:Name="MyList" Grid.Column="0" />


            <Grid x:Name="AppointmentDetailView" Grid.Column="1">
                <!--Some other stuff-->
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

If I set a fixed height on any parent of the `ListView` or the ListView itself the scrolling works as expected but fixing the height is undesirable for screens of varying sizes.  I tried binding to the ActualHeight  of the `ListView`s parents but no luck.

It seems like the `ScrollViewers` children are not constrained to the height available even when the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` is disabled.  Seems rather odd to me, I would have expected the `ScrollViewer`'s layout logic to be similar to `Grid` in the direction it has been disabled.

Any help with this is appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that involves wrapping my `ScrollViewer` in a `Grid` and binding to the outer `Grids` `ActualHeightProperty` on the child element of the `ScrollViewer`. its a bit of a hack but does what I need it to and goes something like this

```
<Grid x:Name="ScrollViewerContainer" ...>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ...>
         <!--Page Content-->
         <Grid Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ScrollViewerContainer}" ...>
              ....
```

Personally I feel like the `ScrollViewer` should not allow its children to determine its `Width/Height` when the scroll mode is disabled in a particular direction as it breaks nested `ScrollViewer`'s.  It should revert back to the available space.  But hey, I'm not Microsoft..